# how to perform if-else drop operation in Apache nifi

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I have a use case where I have couple of key values and perform if-else operation on it. If condition is not matched then whole content will drop, else pass the content as a result.

**Input JSON** :

```json
{
  "id": 30006,
  "SourceName": "network",
  "Number": 1,
  "SourceNameCopy": "network",
  "currenttime": "Thu Aug 30 21:19:27 IST 2022"
}
```

My **Jolt Spec** :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "SourceNameCopy": {
        "network": {
          "@1": "&2",
          "#id": "id",
          "#SourceName": "SourceName",
          "#Number": "Number",
          "#currenttime": "currenttime"
        },
        "hardware": {
          "@1": "&2",
          "#id": "id",
          "#SourceName": "SourceName",
          "#Number": "Number",
          "#currenttime": "currenttime"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Expected **output** :

if condition matched :

```json
{
  "id": 30006,
  "SourceName": "network",
  "Number": 1,
  "SourceNameCopy": "network",
  "currenttime": "Thu Aug 30 21:19:27 IST 2022"
}
```

Else (condition not matched) Drop the whole event as null.

Problem Statement :
The Key values is getting as a string, it should contain actual value in output as a result.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan, I'm looking for SourceNameCopy matches network or hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your aim is to check out the match for value of **`SourceNameCopy`** versus fixed cases ***`network`*** or ***`hardware`***, then add an **`OR`** operator(**`|`**) among them and compare as in the following case within a **shift** transformation spec :

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "SourceNameCopy": {
        "network|hardware": {
          "@2": "" // bring the whole value after going two levels up the tree
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

No need to include nothing about the other cases they would return as **`null`** spontaneously.